# Creating Contacts from Custom Objects

Tags: trigger, triggercontext

Attempting to create an Apex trigger that will create a new contact when a custom object record (Location) is created or updated. I believe I'm not referencing the custom object correctly and the error shows 
**"expecting an equals sign, found ':'".**

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

```
trigger CreateContact on Contact (after insert, after update){

if(Trigger.isInsert){

    List<Contact> ct = new List <Contact>();

    for(Location : trigger.new){

        Contact c = new Contact(Name = Location__c.Contact__c,
                    Location__c=Location__c.name__c,
                    Address__c=Location__c.Address__c,
                    City__c=Location__c.City__c,
                    State__c=Location__c.State_CD__c,
                    Zip__c=Location__c.Zip__c);

        ct.add(c);
    }
    insert ct; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For-each loops (as you're trying here), need to have the following format:

```
for(SomeType variableName: collectionVariable) {
```

Also, since you're trying to create location records, you need to have the trigger work on Location__c, not Contact.

Also, Contact.Name is a read-only property of FirstName and LastName, so you'll need to find a way to split the field in to up to two parts:

```
String[] names = record.Contact__c.split(' ',2); // At most two parts
if(names.length()<2) {
    names.add(null, 0);
}
```

Also, your assignments within the Contact constructor are trying to reference fields (e.g. Location__c.Contact__c, which is an alias for Schema.Location__c.Contact__c), so you need to reference a specific variable name instead.

Finally, since you're not yet doing anything with *after update*, I'd suggest you remove that code until you need it, since you're not using any sort of trigger framework that would benefit from the declaration.

Given the number of problems you're having, I'd probably suggest you try some [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead) exercises if you haven't already.